# $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin^n(x)}{1+x^2} \, dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin^n(x)}{1+x^2} \, dx$$

Is it right answer ?
$$
 \begin{cases}
  0, & x \ne \pi/2\\[8pt]
  \dfrac{2\pi}{4 + \pi^2}, & x = \pi/2
 \end{cases}
$$

Comment: $x$ is the integration variable, not a free parameter. Such limit is clearly zero by the dominated convergence theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer should not depend on anything called $x$, since $x$ is a bound variable, not a free variable, in the integral. For example:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^3 (i^2 + j^2) = \overbrace{(1^2+j^2) + (2^2 + j^2) + (3^2 + j^2)}^{\begin{smallmatrix} \text{No “$i$'' appears here, since $i$ is} \\[3pt] \text{a bound variable in this sum.} \\[3pt] {} \end{smallmatrix}}
$$

---

You have $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{\sin^n x}{1+x^2} = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if }x\ne\dfrac\pi2, \\[8pt] \dfrac 1 {1+\left(\frac\pi2\right)^2} = \dfrac 4 {4+\pi^2} & \text{if } x = \dfrac\pi2. \end{cases} $

And then:
$$
\overbrace{\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin^n x}{1+x^2} \,dx = \int_0^{\pi/2} \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sin^n x}{1+x^2} \, dx}^{\Large\text{Is this valid?}\phantom{\frac 11}}
$$

Interchanging a limit and an integral as above is not always valid, **but it is valid when** the all of the functions in the sequence are "dominated" by one function whose integral is finite. That is **Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem.** We have
$$
\frac{-1}{1+x^2} \le \frac{\sin^n x}{1+x^2} \le \frac 1 {1+x^2}
$$
and we note that

- The function $\dfrac 1 {1+x^2}$ does not depend on the index $n$, and
- Its integral from $0$ to $\pi/2$ is finite.

Hence the dominated convergence theorem can be applied. You then have an integral of a function that is $0$ except at one point. The integral of that function is $0$.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the sequence of functions $f_n (x) = {\sin^n (x)}/({1+x^2})$ on $[0,2\pi]$

If $a \neq \pi/2, 3\pi/2$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, then $|\sin(a)| < 1$, so as $n \to \infty$ we have $f_n (a) \to 0$. Thus, pointwise almost everywhere, as $n\to\infty$ we have $f_n \to 0$.

Let $g(x) = 1/(1+x^2)$. Note that $|f_n (x)| \le |g(x)|$ and $g(x)$ is integrable on $[0,2\pi]$. Hence, by the dominated convergence theorem, it follows $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin^n (x)}{1+x^2} \, dx = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} f_n (x) \, dx = \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n (x) \, dx = \int_{0}^{\pi/2} 0 \, dx = 0.$$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> [Laplace Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method):

\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\sin^n\pars{x} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x & =
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\cos^n\pars{x} \over
1 + \pars{\pi/2 - x}^{2}}\,\dd x =
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\exp\pars{n\ln\pars{\cos\pars{x}}} \over
1 + \pars{\pi/2 - x}^{2}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\exp\pars{-nx^{2}/2} \over
1 + \pars{\pi/2 - 0}^{2}}\,\dd x =
\lim_{n\to\infty}\pars{%
\root{\pi \over 2}\,{4 \over \pi^{2} + 4}\,{1 \over \root{n}}} =
\bbx{\ds{0}}
\end{align}